# PHP + HTML: create a form dynamically

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I'm trying to creat a form dynamically depending on the number of rows of a table in a database. I tried this and it's nor working:

```
require_once('mysqli_connect.php');

//I select the colum w_spanish from the table selected by the user
$q="SELECT w_spanish FROM ".$_GET['name'];

$r=@mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

echo '<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="Correction.php">';
echo '<TABLE BORDER="1">';

//Here is where I generate dinamically a table that can be filled by user
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

$aux=$row['w_spanish'];
echo '<TR><TD>'.$aux.'</TD><TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="Sol_'.$aux.'" SIZE="20"></TD></TR>';

}

echo '</TABLE>';
echo '<P><INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Submit" ></P></FORM>'; 


mysqli_close($dbc);
```

So when I press submit, the information is not sent to "Correction.php", and I think it's because I creating the HTML form inside php code. How could I do it right??

Comment: What happens if you push submit?

Comment: have you verified if the query returns correct result?

Comment: @Bart Friederichs an error trying to call a file that doesn't exist. But Correction.php doest exist (and it's placed in the forrect folder in the server). 

If for example I creat the same form, but in all in HTML, and generating the table with a fixed number of row, everything works fine, and I reach Correction.php perfectly.

Comment: Which file is it trying to fetch then?

Comment: you can create html form inside php code. I don't think that is the problem here.

Comment: @Maximus2012 so is it possible to create a HTML form in the way I'm doing?? It's weird because I tried also with this: 

<body>

<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="Correction.php">
<TABLE BORDER="1">
<TR>
<TD>Your name</TD>
<TD>
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="name" SIZE="20">
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>Your E-mail address</TD>
<TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="email" SIZE="25"></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
<P><INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Submit" NAME="B1"></P>
</FORM>
</body>

And it works perfect.

Comment: yes... your code looks good on that front (with may be some small syntax errors possibly) but as mentioned by Alex Sears, it could be the database query that is causing issue here. A sample output of the query would be helpful here. You can also use sqlfiddle for that.

Comment: @Bart Friederichs well it should fetch Correction.php. But instead I get the tipical error make when I write in the broswer a URL to a file that doesn't exist in the server.

Comment: @user1773841 and what file is that? What's in the address bar?

Comment: @Maximus2012 No the query is nice, because I need to retrieve correctly the information to feel the table, and I'm doing that nice. The problem is when I fill the form and I try to send the information to the file Correction.php

But my main question was it this way to make the form was correctly and you have already answered it. So thank you very mch, I will keep checking the syntax and I will try to validate the HTML as someone said below

Comment: @Bart Friedrichs it's a file that will read the information inserted in the form I wrote in above, and will do some stuff with that information -basically compare with it with other information stored in the database and correct the mistakes-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off - remove the @ from the @mysqli statement as it is masking any errors that maybe happening.

Secondly take the generated code and paste it into http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input and see if there are any HTML errors and adjust where necessary.

Thirdly, since the user can select which table to read then your data needs to be super-sanitised as you certainly don't want sql injection attacks here.

Comment: Thanks!! for all the info. I'm new with PHP and my code is still very messy

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be the query you are running.  Without knowing more information, my guess would be your query isn't getting anything.  Try dumping the row in each iteration and see what spits out. You may be looking for something like:

```
$q="SELECT w_spanish FROM tableName WHERE name = " . $_GET['name'];
```

If that's not it, it could also be the fact that since you are only grabbing one column from the database, you don't need access the information with `$aux=$row['w_spanish'];`.  You can just use:

```
$aux=$row;
```

That I'm not 100% on though.  Try dumping each row with `var_dump()` and see what pops out.

Answer (score -2):

First declare `$row`, then use a do-while loop.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC) do{  
    $aux=$row['w_spanish']; 
    echo '<TR><TD>'.$aux.'</TD><TD><INPUT> TYPE="TEXT"NAME="Sol_'.$aux.'" SIZE="20"></TD></TR>';
 }while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
```

Comment: How does this change anything? manually fetching a row then using a do/while loop is functionally the same as just using a normal while() loop.